# Inferring the Indices of Array Values

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

Given the following code

```
private static final String EPSILON = "";

private static List<String> computeLanguage(char[] alphabet, int n) {
    List language = new ArrayList();
    language.add(EPSILON); // The smallest prefix
    return computeLanguage(alphabet, EPSILON, language, 0, n);
}

private static List<String> computeLanguage(char[] alphabet, String prefix,
        List<String> language, int i, int n) {
    if (i < n) {
        for (char symbol : alphabet) {
    String w = prefix + symbol;
            language.add(w);
            computeLanguage(alphabet, w, language, i + 1, n);
        }
    }
    return language;
}
```

Since the cardinality of `language` is known apriori, so I would like to rewrite the above code such that it uses just the elementary data structure array. Hence `computeLanguage(char[], int)` would look like the following:

```
private static String[] computeLanguage(char[] alphabet, int n) {
    int cardinality = ((int)Math.pow(alphabet.length, n+1) -1)/(alphabet.length -1) ;
    String[] language = new String[cardinality];
    language[0] = EPSILON; // The smallest prefix
    return computeLanguage(alphabet, EPSILON, language, 0, n);
}
```

Furthermore `computeLanguage(char[], String, String[], int, int)` would look like the following:

```
private static String[] computeLanguage(char[] alphabet, String prefix,
        String[] language, int i, int n) {
    if (i < n) {
        for (char symbol : alphabet) {
            String w = prefix + symbol;
            language[X] = w; // What is the value of X
            computeLanguage(alphabet, w, language, i + 1, n);
        }
    }
    return language;
}
```

I got stack on inferring the value of X based on the method parameters `i`, the size of the words `w` might be the foreach loop could be rewrite to `for(int j=0; i<alphabet.length; j++)`, and so on. well there is a straightforward solution that defines a static integer variable `v` such that `language[++v] = w;`

Any hints?

Comment: Nit: don't use raw types `List<String> language = new ArrayList<>();`.

Comment: I would really suggest this is easier to do with a List than an array.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner for your contribution! Sure it is easier, but would it possible to compute the array indices?

Answer (score 0):

I would really suggest this is easier to do with a List than an array.

What you need to do in your code here is to keep track of how many elements you have already put into `language`, and put `w` at the "next slot".

With a list, you don't have to do this management: it does it for you. All you have to use is `List.add` to put it into the next slot.

If what you're really worried about here is having to repeatedly resize the List: just create it with the capacity you know you will eventually need:

```
List<String> languageList = new ArrayList<>(cardinality);
```

---

---

You *can* do this with array indices, it just gets messier.

Basically, you need to pass in the "next slot" as a parameter, and then return the next "next slot" as a return value. (You already have a return value, but it's not useful, so it can be repurposed).

```
private static int computeLanguage(char[] alphabet, String prefix,
        String[] language, int i, int n, int X) {
    if (i < n) {
        for (char symbol : alphabet) {
            String w = prefix + symbol;
            language[X] = w;
            X = computeLanguage(alphabet, w, language, i + 1, n, X + 1);
        }
    }
    return return X;
}

// Call with:
computeLanguage(alphabet, EPSILON, language, 0, n, /* X= */ 0);
return language;
```

I'm not 100% sure this is correct, and this is part of my point about using a `List` instead: it's trivial to reason about. Here, every time you pass, update, reassign or return `X`, there's a possibility of a bug.

---

An alternative to populate an array would be to write a `Consumer<String>` which is a very simple and limited kind of a List:

```
String[] language = new String[size];
Consumer<String> consumer = new Consumer<String>() {
  int nextSlot = 0;

  @Override public void accept(String s) {
    language[nextSlot++] = s;
  }
};
```

and now you can pass that to `computeLanguage`:

```
private static void computeLanguage(char[] alphabet, String prefix,
        Consumer<String> languageConsumer, int i, int n) {
    if (i < n) {
        for (char symbol : alphabet) {
            String w = prefix + symbol;
            languageConsumer.accept(w);
            computeLanguage(alphabet, w, languageConsumer, i + 1, n);
        }
    }
}
```

---

And, a really poor approach would be just to find the first null element in the array:

```
int firstNull = IntStream.range(0, language.length).filter(i -> language[i] == null).findFirst().orElseThrow();
language[firstNull] = w;
```

---

But, just to re-emphasize: use a List. It's the simplest, best way to do this.